# How to give a curvy border to the graph

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: Need to animate the graph]

The template code is something like this.

```
      <div class="percentage-circle-container">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div
          id="activeBorder"
          *ngFor="let perc of percs; let i = index"
          class="circle-{{i+1}} circle-border"
          [ngStyle]="perc"
        ></div>
      </div>
```

The css file looks like this. Includes the height and width of each circle and their respective background color.

```
.percentage-circle-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

  .circle {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    @media (max-width: 450px) and (min-width: 376px) {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
  }
  .active-border {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #ed607c;
    @media (max-width: 450px) and (min-width: 320px) {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
    }
  }
}
.score_percent {
  display: inline-block;
  .avg-score {
    color: #383838;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-family: $font-family-colfax-regular;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    @media (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 400px) {
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      bottom: 31px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 376px) {
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      bottom: 28px;
    }
  }
  .percentage {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ed607c;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    @media (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 400px) {
      font-size: 25px;
      padding-left: 4px;
    }
  }
  .percent_symbol {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ed607c;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 400px) {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
.type2 {
  display: inline-block;
  .percentage-circle-container {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
  }
  .circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 2;
    .text {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: $font-family-colfax-medium;
      color: #383838;
      margin-top: 60px;
      img {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    }

    .percent {
      color: #f56380;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-family: colfax-bold;
    }
  }
  .circle-border {
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .line {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    border-right: 2px solid #e75e79;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    &:before {
      content: "";
      background-color: #e75e79;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -6px;
      left: -2px;
    }
  }

  .circle-5 {
    width: 270px;
    height: 270px;
    background-color: #f56380;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
  }
  .circle-4 {
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    background-color: #ef7f95;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
  }
  .circle-3 {
    width: 310px;
    height: 310px;
    background-color: #f7a1b2;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
  }
  .circle-2 {
    width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #f9c0cb;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .circle-1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #fbdfe5;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

The typescript file looks like this.There are different colors and each color should have a curvy border at the end.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-percentage-circle",
  templateUrl: "./percentage-circle.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./percentage-circle.component.scss"]
})
export class PercentageCircleComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() percentage = 0;
  @Input() type = 1;
  @Input() perCentageArray = [];
  percs = [];
  activeBorderStyle;
  avg;
  colorArray = ["#FBDFE5", "#F9C0CB", "#F7A1B2", "#EF7F95", "#F56380"];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngOnChanges() {
    debugger;
    if (this.type === 2) {
      let i = 0;
      let total = 0;
      this.perCentageArray.forEach(deg => {
        total += deg;
        deg = deg * 3.6;
        let style;
        if (deg <= 180) {
          deg = deg + 90;
          style = {
            "background-image":
              "linear-gradient(" +
              deg +
              "deg, transparent 50%, #ffffff 50%)," +
              "linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, transparent 50%)"
          };
        } else {
          deg = deg - 90;
          style = {
            "background-image":
              "linear-gradient(" +
              deg +
              "deg, transparent 50%, " +
              this.colorArray[i] +
              " 50%)," +
              "linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, transparent 50%)"
          };
        }
        this.percs.push(style);
        this.avg = total / this.perCentageArray.length;
        console.log(this.avg);
        i++;
      });
    } else {
      let deg = this.percentage * 3.6;
      if (deg <= 180) {
        deg = deg + 90;
        this.activeBorderStyle = {
          "background-image":
            "linear-gradient(" +
            deg +
            "deg, transparent 50%, #f2f2f2 50%)," +
            "linear-gradient(90deg, #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 50%)"
        };
      } else {
        deg = deg - 90;
        this.activeBorderStyle = {
          "background-image":
            "linear-gradient(" +
            deg +
            "deg, transparent 50%, #ed607c 50%)," +
            "linear-gradient(90deg, #f2f2f2 50%, transparent 50%)"
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line should have a curvy border at the end.Any help is appreciated and please help your fellow developer. Thanks in advance. For your reference I have added the image that is required in case of any miscommunication
[image: Need something like this with curvy border at the end]

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I would have love to but since all the values are calculated dynamically I am not sure how to do it. Extremely sorry

Comment: This is all I could achieve. Please help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aldppd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts